# How to raster vectors (AI) into 1bit tif in 2000dpi

Tags: adobe-illustrator, dpi, raster

I need to raster files 1m x 0,70m to 1-bit TIFF. Pretty much home RIPing.
AI CS 5.5 only goes until aprox. 500dpi and PS renders vector-PDFs or AIs in 406 dpi max. Then you have to resize x5 to get 2.030dpi, but you of course loose details.

Don't ask me why I need so big file, I just need it. It is only a simple B/W artwork.
Thanks. Help appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to know what output device has 2000dpi??

Comment: @JAG...most film RIPs output at 2000dpi

Comment: Actually, despite your request, I am going to ask why you need such a large file. Knowing why you need something like this might help us offer a better way to accomplish what it is you are doing.

Comment: it is used for navigation of laser engraving machine, only works with 1b tiff

Comment: I think this is one of the few examples where DPI=PPI?

Answer (score 3):

- Import the Illustrator file into Photoshop as a Smart Object `File > Open As Smart Object`.\
- Use `Image > Resize` with "Resample" turned on to change the width to 100cm.
- Be prepared to wait a long time, depending on your RAM and scratch disk (operation may fail if your system isn't up to it).
- `Image > Mode > Greyscale`
- `Image > Mode > Bitmap`
- Save as TIFF

Here's what I get at this point:

[image: Image Size in Photoshop]

Comment: Thanks, but photoshop only allows approx 400dpi for size 1meter by 70cm artwork... please only valid answers... 
I suppose I may need another sw... thankx

Comment: @MJ23 Did you choose Bmp at "image mode"? I think: No. And btw: "please only valid answers" is pretty harsh. Alan Gilbertson gave you an answer and writes that he tried it. I'd suggest to just ask "deeper" if you think he serverd too less detail to recreate his successful test.

Comment: @MJ23: Do the steps that I gave in the answer exactly as laid out. You have a "400 ppi" barrier because you are not doing these steps, not because Photoshop has a limitation.

Comment: I repeat the artwork is 1000mm X 700mm, sometimes more, resulting in approx 78000px x 55000px. I get "Artwork exceeds size and resolution limit" error message from export in IllCS5.5 or in PspCS5.5 i enter everything in the import dialog, the import looks like OK, but final size is allways 32000 *32000px, looks like Psp maximum... later resizing is no option for me..  ***   .

Comment: Sorry if you feel offended, I of course tried that, in fact I tried hundreds of ways but didnt find solution... but if you tell me its my fault and you don't even check if your advice works correctly... btw. try switching "Constrain proportions" on and off in import dialog window and you see the real final image size changes in the input boxes to fit Photoshop import limit".

Comment: I didn't feel in the least offended. Don't forget we get many levels of expertise here. I've added a step to the answer. See if that doesn't get you where you need to be.

Comment: Sorry, but as I said before I cannot resize, I need to render cirle and diagonal lines and resizing them 5X to get 2000+ dpi makes curves too pixelated... **** ... Simply said I am looking for home RIP tool to convert AI (PDF, EPS vector) to 1bit TIFF 2000 or 2540 dpi..., no special needs for halftone rastering, my data are 100% tint...

Comment: If you resize a Smart Object, the vectors are re-rendered at the new resolution. There is no pixelation. Read the Help for Smart Objects.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to export it as postscript and use [ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/8.00/Devices.htm) to render it to a bitmap format.  Ghostscript can render in bands, so it can support very large image sizes.

Comment: looks like a possibility, i'll give it a try...